# $x \in \partial E \iff \exists x_k \subset E$ and $\exists x_j \subset E^C$ such that lim $x_k$= lim $x_j$ = x

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

Let $E$ a set in $\mathbb R^n$, I want to show that $x \in \partial E \iff \exists$ a sequence $x_k \subset E$ and $\exists$ a sequence $x_j \subset E^C$ such that lim $x_k$ = lim $x_j$ = $x$.

I did the $\Longleftarrow$ implication, but I struggle with the $\Longrightarrow$ way, I think I need to build two explicit sequences of limit $x$ by myself but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ball $B(x,\frac1n)$ around $x$ intersects $E$ and $E^\complement$, so we can pic $x_n \in B(x,\frac1n) \cap E$ and $y_n \in B(x,\frac1n) \cap E^\complement$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$.

Then show that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, and these are as required.

It's notationally not very handy to have two sequences $x$ with different index symbols, I find it confusing. The indices $k,j$ are both in $\Bbb N$ presumably, so $x_1$ would be ambiguous: is it from one or the other sequence?